# What are elementary examples of elements and operations on the lamplighter group?

Tags: group-theory, wreath-product

> What are some elementary examples of elements and operations on the [Lamplighter group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamplighter_group) $L$?

I have the definition above which is the infinite sum of infinitely many copies of the cyclic group $C_2$, and I can tentatively work out what this means, but not confidently.

It looks to me like any given element of $L$ comprises the ordered pair $a,z$ where $a$ is a binary string starting and ending in $1$ and $z$ is any integer but I'm not sure about this as I'm struggling to understand the concept of the wreath product.

I want to categorise its similarities and differences to other algebras containing a binary string and an action of $\Bbb Z$ such as the multiplicative monoid $\Bbb Z[\frac12]^+/\langle2\rangle$ or even the group $\Bbb Q^+/\langle2\rangle$.

If I understand correctly then $a,b\in L$ are examples of two elements:

$a=(10100101_2,7)$

$b=(111_2,2)$

Then I'm guessing but I'd say to combine them, offset each by $z$ digits and $\mathrm{XOR}$ adjacent elements to get:

$a\circ b=(1010010100111,2)$

I'd estimate the probability of this being correct is pretty slim.

Comment: I haven't checked  the first component, but the second component of $a \circ b$ is certainly $7+2=9$. Also note that your binary strings can extend in both directions, so you need to mark where the $0$-component is.

Comment: Thanks @DerekHolt .  The way I've formulated it, (by requiring binary strings that start and end in $1$), I was intending the $z^{th}$ digit from the right to mark the $0$-component. I was thinking this is the role of $z$. (even then I've done it wrong)

Comment: @DerekHolt so in my example I'm just doing $101001010000000_2\mathrm{XOR}11100_2=101001010011100_2$

Comment: You cannot simultaneously require that the string ends in $1$ and that the $z$th digit from the right is the 0-component. Not all elements have that property.

Comment: @DerekHolt I'm imagining infinitely many zeroes either side. What is clear is that I don't understand this group!